# Crawler4j, Jsoup and JavaScript: extract attribute values modified with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, web-crawler, jsoup, crawler4j

I'm using a Crawler4j and Jsoup to crawl a website and it works fine for the HTML text, but there are some important contents, which default values are hard coded in CSS and then dynamically set with JavaScript.
For example, I have the 
and I need the width value, which in CSS is hard coded as 10px, but modified in JavaScript to, let's say, 5px.

Is there a way to get this value without using another crawler? Or a simple alternative?
I have already quite a lot of code, so I don't want to rewrite everything if there is a possibility to do that with the Crawler4j.

I hope my question is clear enough and thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You want be able to achieve your goal with Jsoup, because this tool can only download static html content. I am not familiar with Crawler4j, but I made a quick look at documentation and didn't found anything about executing javascript. You should consider using tool, that simulates browser, i.e. execute javascript code like HtmlUnit or Selenium

Comment: Okay, thank you, I'll try out a headless browser I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with `crawler4j` nor with `jsoup`. They both handle only static HTML content.

There are several open issues related dynamic JavaScript execution on the official GitHub Repository: [#49](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/issues/49), [#197](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/issues/197) and  [#220](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/issues/220).

To achieve your objectives, you would need to build a stack based on [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/), [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) and/or [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), which could then be used for advanced crawling including JavaScript execution.